# Lets upgrade answers

Tags: feature-request, answers

Take a look at `Lukasz 'Severiaan' Grela`'s [cloning and upgrading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29792507/1129332) of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24660825/1129332), instead of editing it.

And I completely understand why Lukasz did that: there is no reward for edits, but Lukasz did a hard job of refactoring the answer, so he wants to get reputation for that.

However it resulted in two bad things:

- Lukasz's answer is not stand alone, as he has a lot of references to my answer. So you need to read both to understand him.
- My answer is not as good as it could be if I were using Lukasz's upgrade, for the readers is better to read Lukasz's answer.

So here is an idea for a solution: Add the option to **Upgrade an Answer!**

Here how it works:

- Instead of providing a new answer for a question, you will upgrade an existing answer.
- Since upgrading also mean modifying an existing answer, it will be voted, just the way close and open questions work. The voters will get 3 options:

  - Approve merge
  - Convert merge to edit
  - Reject merge
- Approved merges will give equal amount of reputation to all contributors, equals to 10 points for each contributor for every up-vote and -2 for every down-vote. New contributors do not get points for prevues up/down votes.
- If merge become an edit, well that the risk your are taking when merging. You will not get any reputation for it.
- If merge is rejected the answer will not be effected, and the merge will be deleted.
- You can also suggest merging two existing questions, in that case is very similar for editing, you will not get any reputation for it, unless one of the answers is yours.
- In case where two existing answers been merged two one, the reputation of the authors of the answers will not be effected and the new score of the answer will be the sum of the existing votes of the unmerged answers.
- During the time when there is a suggestion for merge the merge will be presented as a regular answer with one exception: The title of this answer will have a link to the answer that it wants to merge in. The users will be able to cast their votes on this answer, how ever until the merge is approved only the author of this merge will get the reputation.

  - If merge is rejected the suggested merge answer is getting deleted, and all the score for it been reset.
  - If merge converted to edit, all the score is been reset.

[James](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254134/246587) made a good point about `piggy-people`, that might want to upgrade famous answers. I think that merge should be done only by users with high rep of 2000+, also Merge is been voted and answers may got deleted, so this feature is protected by the community and there for, the chances to see `piggy-people` is small.

Comment: @Mat I am android developer, I can tell you that many times I saw answers, that been very similar to what I about to answer, and this is why I didn't answer, but I could improve many of them. I can now. It just don't like editing.

Answer (score 9):

> Take a look at this guy, Lukasz 'Severiaan' Grela, he preferred
>   cloning my answer and upgrading it, instead of editing it.

Just to note: I don't think in this case Lukasz particularly did anything wrong.

If someone just copy/pastes your answer into their own answer, then it could perhaps be unfair.

However in this case they:

- Gave you *clear recognition*: "Modification of @Ilya_Gazman answer" so
  were not trying to claim your code as their own
- Added descriptions of their own
- Added code to their answer in addition to your code, in that they had
  an additional class which extends another class, which yours does
  not.

However, if it's required to read your answer in order to understand their answer, then their answer is not very good and needs downvotes and a friendly comment.

### Your proposal

> "Upgrade an Answer"
>
> 1. Both the person who made the upgrade and the person who gave the
>      answer will receive reputation.
> 2. In case the upgrade is not approved it will become an edit.
> 3. Possible to merge somebody else answer to an upgrade of different
>      answer, merge will be voted and if approved both answers will be
>      merged two one (no bonus for the person who made the merge).

This introduces numerous complexities, and all sorts of contrasting and potentially conflicting things, both from users and site functionality.

Normally a feature-request doesn't have to provide "how" it would work, but I have delved into that as it's the main issue really.

Also, forgive any mistakes or my being "blunt", I just quickly wrote down some possible issues, complications, and considerations.
 It almost frazzled my brain thinking about all the permutations.

In response to your points above:

**1)**

- How much rep each?    Do they share the current rep somehow, or are
  we giving out double rep for the same answers? Or no change for
  author and "upgrade" gets a bit less?
- What happens in a rollback? Does rep get returned, lost? Does the
  answer become "unmerged" and back into it's own answer?
- People will "upgrade" other users' *very popular* answers just to
  "piggy-back" them to get some rep.   This will "likely" be a *fair
  sized* problem.
- Also you are changing the way the voting works.   In that instead of
  just voting and giving answerer 10 rep, you are also giving someone
  else rep, and that means reading the review history to see what the
  "upgrade" was and if you want to give them rep for what they added or
  not.
- What if answer is great and should get upvote and rep, but you
  don't want to give "upgrader" any rep - or vice versa?    And all of
  this is the same for downvoting.

**2)**

- If the "upgrade" is not approved what makes it worthy of being an
  edit? You could stack them up, so if "upgrade" not approved it turns
  into a "suggested edit", but then you have to work out rep and
  privileges.
- Can users "upgrade" without approval? Does a rejected "upgrade" made
  by a 2K user get auto approved as an edit? Then author rejecting
  "upgrade" will be annoyed because changes went through anyway.

**3)**

- Do we add a new "Merge Review Queue" so "suggested merges" can
  happen? Or is this based on rep, like suggested edits vs 2K auto
  edit? Or both?
- "no bonus for the person who made the merge" So why would this
  encourage people to do it? People get 2 rep for suggesting edits.
- What happens if both answers are not yours? Or if one answer is yours
  and another someone else's? Who authorises merges - one author or
  both, and/or mixed and review queue?
- What happens to the rep on both answers?   You cannot merge them.
  What if answerA is being merged to answerB, and answerA has -3
  downvotes? If they are transferred in the merge then author of
  answerB get's downvotes? Do we give them the negative rep?
- Are the downvotes lost, so then people would use this to lose
  downvotes and at the same time piggy-back a better answer and
  potentially get rep? Or does the author of the answer being merged
  away keep their downvotes, but it does not show on the answer it's
  being merged to? So user has -2 rep but answer doesn't reflect it.
- What happens to the answer while it's a "suggested merge"? What if
  author of the answer waiting to be merged away wants to edit their
  answer, or someone else does?

---

---

There are all sorts of other complications and issues with all of this, and I think while I've highlighted the main ones I can think of, I've probably only scratched the surface.
And when you consider what return this gives us, given we already have edits, I just don't see it being worthwhile at all.

The idea itself is not too bad, and could actually bring about some really interesting options.
However, with the way the site works, I just don't think it would ever comfortably slot into the functions, community moderation, voting, etc.

Comment: I strongly think that OP isn't trying to cast Lukasz's actions in a negative view - OP has said that Lukasz's actions are understandable, has acknowledged that OP's answer has attribution, and admits that OP's own answer is not as good as it was, but because it has more upvotes than Lukasz's better answer, the more deserving answer might get less attention from new users. Their command of the language might not be that good, so could you please tone down your own initial paragraphs?

Comment: @muru the proposal is based around the scenario where OP had their answer taken, instead of editing or "upgrading", So I thought it prudent to explain that there was no harm done in this case. I meant nothing snarky or that requires "toning down" really. It's just facts :)

Comment: @James I edited the question, to answer your questions. About the idea that you want to choose to which contributor you are giving your vote, I think it's inappropriate, you simply vote for the answer and for all the contributors equally.